# Firefox doesnt show pseudo selectors created by insertRule

Tags: javascript, firefox

My problem exists only in mozilla (in chrome and opera, it works fine).

html:

```
<div id="map">
  <img src="img/world-map.png" alt="" usemap="#Map" />
    <map name="Map" id="Map">    

    <area number="1" city-display="japan" description="Tokio, Japan" shape="circle" coords="958,306,20" />
    <area number="2" city-display="beijing" description="Beijing, The Great Wall of China" shape="circle" coords="880,290,20" />
    <area number="3" city-display="sydney" description="Sydney,Australia" shape="circle" coords="998,551,20" />
  </map>
</div>
```

css:

```
area:hover:before{
content: '';
background-color: rgba(26, 34, 34, 0.7);
color: #ffffff;
border: 1px solid black;
border-radius: 3px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 99;
```

js

```
var style = document.createElement('style');

document.body.appendChild(style);

document.getElementById('map').addEventListener('mouseover',function(x){

    var mouseX = x.pageX;
    var mouseY = x.pageY;
    var map = document.getElementById('map');

    if(x.target && x.target.nodeName == 'AREA'){


        style.sheet.insertRule("area:nth-of-type(" 
            + x.target.getAttribute('number') 
            + "):hover::before{top:" 
            + (mouseY - 25) +"px;" 
            +"left:" + (mouseX -5 ) + "px; " 
            + "content:'" + x.target.getAttribute('description') 
            + "';}",0); 

        this.addEventListener('click',function(){

        style.sheet.insertRule("#" + x.target.getAttribute('city-display') +"{display:block;}",0)

        });


          console.log('dsf');

    }

});
```

Script just takes elements from image map and add dynamic pseudo elements with description, as i noticed its not working only in single browser - firefox

[image: working before and after hover img]

Comment: can you build the rules for all of them at load instead of one-at-a-time upon hover? i'm thinking that the hover rule must be present when the hover starts or it won't show...

Comment: i did as you suggested, and again firefox is not working, opera/ie/chrome are fine

Comment: it might be related to `x.pageX`. i would console.log() the values you feed in and see where it's breaking down. if the css works for one being hard-coded, it must be the JS that's the issue.

Comment: seems like firefox have problems with showing pseudoelements for area tag, i just simply added span tag to my map, changed `:hover::before ` -> `hover ~ span:before` and its working, css - `area:hover:before` -> `area:hover ~span:before`